# How to bypass firewall protection to hack windows server 2003?

Tags: windows, firewalls, metasploit

I am trying to hack windows server 2003 sp2, i can see a lot of services running on target, there is also a lot of backdoors  listing on ports like netbus, remote-everything ....
But Firewall (as i guess) is refusing any tcp connection, except on some ports
is there any way to bypass the firewall?

note: I am using Metasploit

Comment: UDP spoofing is my best guess, can you tell which version of the networking it runs?

Comment: We would need a lot more data about your testing setup to really help. Can you run a packet sniffer on the server to see if your packets are reaching your target?

Comment: OK I see sp2 havent read it - with this you can maybe crash firewall? Do you know what hardware does it run?

Comment: i ma sure that packets are reaching firewall, because when metasploit tries to create the reverse connection, i receive a message says : connection refused by host

Comment: i do not know what u exactly mean by version of networking, i am working on a LAN, and there is one 3layer switch between my machine and target machine,

Comment: what information about the hardware u want to know?? target is a normal pc working as a server, 2.00 GB of RAM, intel(R) core(TM)2 Duo  E7500 @ 2.93GHz

Comment: how to run packet sniffer on the server??!!! i do not have access i am working to hack it

Comment: Do you have any access to the DNS server? Have you tried to change your ip to be similar to windows one? It really could be that easy and works very often.

Comment: ps. make sure that you are not doing anything illegal, because if you gonna make ip conflict, you will be arrested by net-admin and given out to the police. You can cause death with this, as it happened on train in china once.

Comment: in fact my target works as proxy server, DNS server in the same time, i can reach the target easily, so why i need to get ip in same subnet, the firewall preventing connection is\ on the target machine (windows server 2003) not in the middle

Comment: in fact, i am doing a penetration testing for my university network, as a graduation project :), so every thing is legal, so do not worry and do not hesitate to help

Comment: Think about your comment: "when metasploit tries to create the reverse connection, i receive a message says : connection refused by host" Who is generating that message?

Comment: ok the message says : The connection was refused by the remote host , i think i forgot to add  the word remote

Answer (score 2):

The 'best' way to bypass a firewall is client-side. Get a payload to a user on the target, which connects back out. Emails and browsers are the most common.

Comment: in fact my target is a server used as a proxy. there are no users to surf net or opening emails on this machine